# Chart.js color is not working in IE

Tags: javascript, charts

I have a chart using Chart.js that works fine in all browsers except IE. In other browsers the chart background color and border is showing up red but in IE it just renders as black.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Chart Test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="dist/Chart.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="load()">
    <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script>
function load()
{
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'line',
data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
    }]
},
options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero:true
            }
        }]
    }
}
});
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39335137/5090771)...

Comment: Yep that worked for me thanks